# How to get items from cart at homepage when there is NO API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've added items to a cart and I need to be able to create a popup on the homepage of the items in the cart after the user is on a specific place on the page.  The problem is that when i'm on the homepage you can not access the items in that cart.
(*BTW i have to do this on the console of the website)

I could not find the API to be able to retrieve a JSON object so I figured I could fetch to "website.com/cart" which gives me a HTML string in return.  But this is where i am having problems.

How can I properly use jQuery to scrape that html string for the items? The html string is also very long, it isnt efficient to append the whole string to the page...
Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.You have not included syntactically valid code. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood is that the list of items in the cart must have had been sent to the server, since you've thought about querying `website.com/cart`. If so, make an API in your backend that you can query from your application using `$.post` or `$.get` and retrieve cart details in JSON format that you can work on

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to inject the entire HTML string into the page to use jQuery on it. If you do:

```
const page = $(html);
```

...that will parse the HTML into DOM elements that are detached from the page, and you can query child elements:

```
const items = page.find('.cart-item');
```

But in case you haven't fully ruled it out, check to see if the cart page makes any XHR/fetch requests when it loads; maybe there *is* an endpoint you can call to get the data directly so you can avoid the "screen scraping" approach.